# Repeat a table at the beginning of each page

Tags: php, drupal, tcpdf

I am using PHP to generate a report dynamically. TCPDF is used to generate a PDF. I want to repeat a particular table at the beginning of each page. How can I detect the page breaks and do this?

```
$result_1      =db_query($sql_1);
while($row_1=db_fetch_array($result_1)) 
{
$table=
<tr><td width=100><b>Name</b></td>
<td width=50><b>No</b></td>
<td width=50><b>Date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=100>'.$row_1['name'].'</td>
<td width=50>'.$row_1['no'].'</td>
<td width=50>'.$row_1['date'].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
}
```

I want to show that particular table at the beginning of each page. There are few other tables also in that while loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the table header to be on each page you make use of the `<thead>` tag.

ie.

```
$result_1      =db_query($sql_1);
$table='
<thead>
 <tr>
<th width=100><b>Name</b></th>
<th width=50><b>No</b></th>
<th width=50><b>Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>';
while($row_1=db_fetch_array($result_1)){
$table.='

<tr>
<td width=100>'.$row_1['name'].'</td>
<td width=50>'.$row_1['no'].'</td>
<td width=50>'.$row_1['date'].'</td>
</tr>
';
}


$table .='</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the TCPDF class and provide a custom function to render your header, which I believe will then be included at the top of every page.

There's an example of the code involved [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps), and a load more TCPDF examples [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php). You could use that example in conjunction with [this one](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps) to do exactly what you need.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the code for the one table in a seperate PHP file and use Include() just before the rest of the table output. This way when you include the page, it will run the DB query for it's self.

Comment: then how it detect the page breaks.

Comment: if its a new page only i want to show this table.Not along with each table

Comment: Ok so I might not understand what your asking. So you want the <tr><td width=100><b>Name</b></td>
<td width=50><b>No</b></td>
<td width=50><b>Date</td>
</tr> Part to be on top of each table like a table header?

Comment: wait NVM I get it... you are making a PDF... so when the HTML data had gone past a "Page" you want the heading to show up and continue printing the data right?

Comment: that is another issue i am facing.i will make u this question sipler..is it possible to detect a pagebreak??.so that that i can put condition like..
if(pagebreak)
{
$pdf->writeHTML($table,true, false, false, false, '');
}

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand you exactly...but if you want this code to be implemented in all your site pages....and see this table at all your site pages you can do tha following 2 ways

1-by creating block and add this block at the top of your pages like the following

- enable php filter module from /admin/build/modules
- create a new block from admin/build/block/add/ and change input format to php format and add your php code in this block content
- add this block at the top of your theme

2- simply add your code at the top of  page.tpl.php theme file

i hop that will help u